# boost::python protected destructor issue

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, boost, boost-python

```
namespace test_py
{

class Event
{
public:
    enum Type { BEGIN = 0, RESULT, END };

    Type get_type( ) const { return m_type; }

protected:
    Event( ) { }
    ~Event( ) { }
    Type m_type;
};

class EventBegin : public Event
{
public:
    EventBegin( ) { m_type = Event::BEGIN; }
    ~EventBegin( ) {}
};

class EventResult : public Event
{
public:
    EventResult( int result ) { m_type = Event::RESULT; m_result = result; }
    ~EventResult( ) {}
    int get_result( ) { return m_result; }

protected:
    int m_result;
};

class EventEnd : public Event
{
public:
    EventEnd( ) { m_type = Event::END; }
    ~EventEnd( ) {}
};

class EventListener
{
public:
    virtual void on_event( const Event& event ) = 0;
};


struct EventListenerWrap: EventListener, py::wrapper< EventListener >
{
    void
    on_event( const Event& event )
    {
        this->get_override( "on_event" )( event );
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( test_py )
{
    {
        py::scope outer = py::class_< Event, boost::noncopyable >( "Event", py::no_init )
            .add_property( "event_type", &Event::get_type );

        py::enum_< Event::Type >( "EventType" )
            .value( "BEGIN", Event::BEGIN )
            .value( "RESULT", Event::RESULT )
            .value( "END", Event::END )
            .export_values( );
    }

    {
        py::class_< EventBegin, py::bases< Event > >( "EventBegin" );
    }

    {
        py::class_< EventResult, py::bases< Event > >( "EventResult", py::no_init )
            .def( py::init< int >( ( py::arg( "result" ) ) ) )
            .add_property( "result", &EventResult::get_result );
    }

    {
        py::class_< EventEnd, py::bases< Event > >( "EventEnd" );
    }

    {
        py::class_< EventListenerWrap, boost::noncopyable >( "EventListener", py::no_init )
            .def( "on_event", py::pure_virtual( &EventListener::on_event ) );
    }
}

}
```

I have a protected constructor and destructor in Event base class and cannot change that.
In Python 2.7 I need to derive from EventListener class and send pointer back to C++ code.
During compilation I got error like that:

```
/boost/python/detail/destroy.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::python::detail::value_destroyer<false>::execute(const volatile T*) [with T = test_py::Event]’:
/boost/python/detail/destroy.hpp:95:36:   required from ‘void boost::python::detail::destroy_referent_impl(void*, T& (*)()) [with T = const test_py::Event]’
/boost/python/detail/destroy.hpp:101:39:   required from ‘void boost::python::detail::destroy_referent(void*, T (*)()) [with T = const test_py::Event&]’
/boost/python/converter/rvalue_from_python_data.hpp:135:71:   required from ‘boost::python::converter::rvalue_from_python_data<T>::~rvalue_from_python_data() [with T = const test_py::Event&]’
/boost/python/converter/arg_from_python.hpp:107:8:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::caller_arity<2u>::impl<F, Policies, Sig>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with F = void (test_py::EventListener::*)(const test_py::Event&); Policies = boost::python::default_call_policies; Sig = boost::mpl::vector3<void, test_py::EventListener&, const test_py::Event&>; PyObject = _object]’
/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:38:33:   required from ‘PyObject* boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<Caller>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with Caller = boost::python::detail::caller<void (test_py::EventListener::*)(const test_py::Event&), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector3<void, test_py::EventListener&, const test_py::Event&> >; PyObject = _object]’
EventListener.cpp:193:1:   required from here
EventListener.cpp:18:5: error: ‘test_py::Event::~Event()’ is protected
     ~Event( ) { }
     ^
In file included from /boost/python/converter/rvalue_from_python_data.hpp:10:0,
                 from /boost/python/converter/registry.hpp:9,
                 from /boost/python/converter/registered.hpp:8,
                 from /boost/python/object/make_instance.hpp:10,
                 from /boost/python/object/make_ptr_instance.hpp:8,
                 from /boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:11,
                 from /boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
                 from /boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from /boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
                 from /boost/python/object/class.hpp:9,
                 from /boost/python/class.hpp:13,
                 from ../../defs.hpp:6,
                 from ../defs.hpp:3,
                 from defs.hpp:3,
                 from EventListener.cpp:1:
/boost/python/detail/destroy.hpp:33:9: error: within this context
         p->~T();
         ^
```

Comment: I didn't analyze your code too much, but, do you, by any chance assign the pointer of a derived class to a base class pointer, and try to delete it via the base class pointer?

Answer (score 1):

```
    py::scope outer = py::class_< Event, boost::noncopyable >( "Event", py::no_init )
        .add_property( "event_type", &Event::get_type );
```

First glance tells me you have a problem here. `py::class_<Event, ...>` only knows about binding to the `Event`, which has the protected destructor.

You're going to have to wrap `Event` in a class that exposes the destructor publically.

If that's not possible (because you cant change the definition of `EventBegin`, `EventEnd` etc for example) then you're going to have to write a polymorphic container that holds on to the derived classes through its own internal interface, internally treating the events as non-polymorphic objects.

This is not as difficult as it sounds:

```
#include <memory>
namespace test_py
{

    class Event
    {
    public:
        enum Type { BEGIN = 0, RESULT, END };

        Type get_type( ) const { return m_type; }

    protected:
        Event( ) { }
        ~Event( ) { }
        Type m_type;
    };

    class EventBegin : public Event
    {
    public:
        EventBegin( ) { m_type = Event::BEGIN; }
        ~EventBegin( ) {}
    };

    class EventResult : public Event
    {
    public:
        EventResult( int result ) { m_type = Event::RESULT; m_result = result; }
        ~EventResult( ) {}
        int get_result( ) { return m_result; }

    protected:
        int m_result;
    };

    class EventEnd : public Event
    {
    public:
        EventEnd( ) { m_type = Event::END; }
        ~EventEnd( ) {}
    };

    class EventProxy
    {
        // define an interface for turning a non-polymorphic event
        // into a polymorphic one
        struct concept
        {
            virtual const Event* as_event() const = 0;
            virtual ~concept() = default;
        };

        // define a model to support the polymorphic interface for a 
        // non-polymorphic concrete object
        template<class T> struct model : concept
        {
            template<class...Args> model(Args&&... args)
            : _event(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
            {}

            const Event* as_event() const override {
                return &_event;
            }

            T _event;
        };

        // construct the model that contains any Event
        template<class T>
        EventProxy(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr)
        : _impl(std::move(ptr))
        {}

    public:
        // T should be derived from Event...
        template<class T, class...Args>
        static EventProxy create(Args&&... args)
        {
            return EventProxy(std::make_shared<model<T>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        }

        // simply return the address of the internal non-polymorphic event    
        const Event* as_event() const {
            return _impl->as_event();
        }

        // return a shared pointer that points to the internal Event BUT
        // defers lifetime ownership to our internal shared_ptr to 
        // our model. This means we never invoke the polymorphic
        // destructor of Event through the protected interface. 
        std::shared_ptr<const Event> as_shared_event() const {
            return std::shared_ptr<const Event>(_impl, _impl->as_event());
        }

    private:
        // lifetime of the proxy is owned by this shared_ptr.
        std::shared_ptr<concept> _impl;
    };

}

// a quick test.    
auto main() -> int
{
    auto ep = test_py::EventProxy::create<test_py::EventBegin>();

    const test_py::Event* p = ep.as_event();

    std::shared_ptr<const test_py::Event> sp = ep.as_shared_event();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Richard for quick reply, but it's still not clear for me how to use that new EventProxy class in python bindings. Could you, please, add this piece of code to your example?

Comment: The eventproxy class gives you a pointer to the event, which you can use in the python bindings. Its purpose is to decouple the deleter from the Event interface.

Comment: So you would use a py::class_<EventProxy,...> in place of the py::class<Event>. You can put as many methods on he proxy as you need. It's even copyable.

Comment: It is possible to expose a class that does not provide publicly-accessible constructors or a destructor by supplying `boost::noncopyable` to suppress automatic to-Python (by-value) converters and providing `boost::python::no_init` as the initialization spec.

Answer (score 0):

When exposing a function, Boost.Python will generate converters for each of the arguments.   For arguments with types `T` and `T&`, the resulting Python converter will hold a copy of the object, and hence needs access to the copy-constructor and destructor.  The rationale for this behavior is to prevent accidentally exposing dangling references.  The same holds true when passing C++ arguments to Python.

This behavior presents a problem when:

- exposing `EventListener::on_event(const Event&)`, as Boost.Python is attempting to create an object that will hold a copy of the `Event`.  To resolve this, consider exposing an auxiliary function that accepts a `Event*`, and then delegates to the original function.
- passing an `Event` object to the Python in `EventListenerWrap::on_event`.  To resolve this, consider wrapping the argument in `boost::ref()` or `boost::python::ptr()`.

Be aware that by not creating copies, it creates the chance for dangling references.  If the actual `Event` object is owned by Python, then its lifetime needs to be at least as long as any reference to it in C++.  Likewise.  If the actual `Event` object is owned by C++, then its lifetime needs to be at least as long as any reference to it in Python.

```cpp
struct EventListenerWrap
  : EventListener,
    boost::python::wrapper<EventListener>
{
  void on_event(const Event& event)
  {
    this->get_override("on_event")(boost::ref(event));
  }
};

/// @brief Auxiliary function that will delegate to EventListener::on_event and
///        avoid by-value conversions at the language boundary.  This prevents
///        prevents Boost.Python from creating instance holders that would hold
///        the value as an rvalue.
void event_listener_on_event_aux(EventListener& listener, Event* event)
{
  return listener.on_event(*event);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(...)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<EventListenerWrap, boost::noncopyable>("EventListener")
    .def("on_event", python::pure_virtual(&event_listener_on_event_aux))
    ;
}
```

An interesting detail is that `boost::python::pure_virtual()` will duplicate the signature of the function it wraps, but it will never actual invoke the wrapped function.  Hence, the wrapped function could have a no-op/empty implementation, but providing an implementation is a good idea incase the `pure_virtual` designator is removed or if the auxiliary function is invoked directly.

Also, note that to allow a Python class to derive from a Boost.Python class, the Boost.Python must expose an `__init__()` method.  Providing no methods, such as by using `boost::python::no_init()`, will result in a runtime error.

---

Here is a minimal complete example based on the original code that [demonstrates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52253564d96cd560) exposing a class with protected constructor and destructor, two derived classes, and virtual dispatch of the derived classes through Boost.Python:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

// Legacy API.
class event
{
public:
  std::string name;
protected:
  event(std::string name) : name(name) {}
  ~event() = default;
};

struct event_a: event { event_a(): event("event_a") {} };
struct event_b: event { event_b(): event("event_b") {} };

class event_listener
{
public:
  virtual void on_event(const event& event) = 0;
};

// Boost.Python helper types and functions.

struct event_listener_wrap
 : event_listener,
   boost::python::wrapper<event_listener>
{
  void on_event(const event& event)
  {
    std::cout << "event_listener_wrap::on_event()" << std::endl;
    this->get_override("on_event")(boost::ref(event));
  }
};

/// @brief Auxiliary function that will delegate to EventListener::on_event and
///        avoid by-value conversions at the language boundary.  This prevents
///        prevents Boost.Python from creating instance holders that would hold
///        the value as an rvalue.
void event_listener_on_event_wrap(event_listener& listener, event* event)
{
  return listener.on_event(*event);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Expose event and suppress default by-value converters and initailizers.
  // This will prevent Boost.Python from trying to access constructors and
  // destructors.
  python::class_<event, boost::noncopyable>("Event", python::no_init)
    .def_readonly("name", &event::name)
    ;

  // Expose event_a and event_b as derived from event.
  python::class_<event_a, python::bases<event>>("EventA");
  python::class_<event_b, python::bases<event>>("EventB");

  // Expose event_listener_wrap.
  python::class_<event_listener_wrap, boost::noncopyable>("EventListener")
    .def("on_event", python::pure_virtual(&event_listener_on_event_wrap))
    ;

  // Expose a function that will perform virtual resolution.
  python::def("do_on_event", &event_listener_on_event_wrap);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> class Listener(example.EventListener):
...     def on_event(self, event):
...         assert(isinstance(event, example.Event))
...         print "Listener::on_event: ", event, event.name
... 
>>> listener = Listener()
>>> listener.on_event(example.EventA())
Listener::on_event:  <example.EventA object at 0x7f3bc1176368> event_a
>>> example.do_on_event(listener, example.EventB())
event_listener_wrap::on_event()
Listener::on_event:  <example.Event object at 0x7f3bc1246fa0> event_b
```

When Python is directly aware of method, it will invoke it without passing through Boost.Python.  Notice how `listener.on_event()` did not get dispatched through C++, and `event` object maintains its `example.EventA` type.  On the other hand, when dispatching is forced into C++, upcasting will not occur.  When `Listener.on_event()` is invoked through `example.do_on_event()`, the `event` object's type is `example.Event` and not `example.EventB`.